# How to get photo location by latitude and longitude in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, latitude-longitude

How to get photo location by latitude and longitude in android? I already get the lat and lon, now I want to fetch photo location by lat and lon that i get before.

Comment: what you have tried, please add codes.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I have no idea, I will try your answer later, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places API now supports the return of one place photo if available for a [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) request and up to ten place photos for a [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) request.

If a photos array is returned with your request, you can pass the photo_reference from a contained photo object to a [Place Photo](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) request with the maxheight and/or maxwidth, sensor and key parameters:

Here is great tutorial: [**Showing nearby places with photos at any location in Google Maps Android API V2**](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-with-photos-at-any-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`Geocoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) API to get address (If I am not mistaken, by location you mean address) for any latitude and longitude. It's [`getFromLocation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) method will fetch the address.

[Working example](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)